# How would you model this part of handle?

Tags: modeling

Im trying some handpainting and actuallyi stuck on a part of modeling ..
the handle .. how would you model this part ?

[image]

I tried to make use Shrink but didnt worked out as i wanted ..
Maybe you guys got an Idea

Would be Great .

Greetings
Marc

Comment: Have you tried sculpting it from a simple cylinder mesh?

Comment: no, not yet . I tried to use the Knifetool to follow the form.  duplicate it and use the solidify modifier . kinda works but idk if its the best method